# How many request can I make in a day in google page insight API?

Tags: google-api

How many request can I make in a day in google page insight API?

Answer (score 0):

After creating a project you can check your quota limits

1. PageSpeed Insight:

   25 000 requests per day;
   1 000 requests per 100 seconds;
   60 requests per 100 seconds per user.
2. Mobile-Friendly Test:

   1 request per 100 seconds.
3. Safe Browsing:

   10 000 requests per day;
   3 000 requests per 100 seconds per user.

source: https://support.netpeaksoftware.com/en-us/article/92-how-to-get-api-token-for-google-services-pagespeed-insights-mobile-friendly-test-and-safe-browsing